# Rings of class of subsets

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Suppose $\mathcal{E}$ is any class of subsets of some set $X$. Consider the class $\mathcal{R}$ of all sets $A\subset X$ such that $A$ is contained in the union of a finite number of  sets in $\mathcal{E}$. Evidently $\mathcal{R}$ is a ring, **and $\mathcal{R}$ contains $\mathcal{E}$, hence $\mathcal{R}$ contains $\mathcal{R(E)}$.**

$\mathcal{R(E)}$ is the intersection of all rings containing $\mathcal{E}$, where $\mathcal{R}$ is a nonempty class of subsets of $X$ called a ring if it is closed under union and set difference of elements in $\mathcal{R}$.

My question is about the last part in the first paragraph. We have that for every $A\in\mathcal{R}$, $A\subset \cup_{j=1}^n E_j$, where $E_j\in \mathcal{E}$.  Somehow it feels that $\mathcal{E}$ is bigger than $\mathcal{R}$, because e.g. $E_j$ covers a part of $A$, but this does not imply that $E_j\subset A$ (and that we can prove with this $\mathcal{E}\subset \mathcal{R}$). The last part is also more misterious to me because from the beginning $\mathcal{R}$ seems smaller from $\mathcal{E}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We have that for every $A\in\mathcal{R}$, $A\subset \cup_{j=1}^n E_j$, where $E_j\in \mathcal{E}$.  Somehow it feels that $\mathcal{E}$ is bigger than $\mathcal{R}$

Is that so? What if I take $A=E$ for $E\in\mathcal{E}$? Every element of $\mathcal{E}$ trivially belongs to $\mathcal{R}$ since it is a subset of itself (which is a union of one-element family).

Here's a concrete example: consider the set of all naturals $\mathbb{N}$. Now take $\mathcal{E}=\{\mathbb{N}\}$ and so $\mathcal{E}$ has exactly $1$ element. Then $\mathcal{R}=P(\mathbb{N})$ the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, which we know is not only infinite but also uncountable. Also $\mathcal{E}\subsetneq\mathcal{R}$. Which one is bigger? You are right that in a sense $\mathcal{E}$ still covers $\mathcal{R}$, but often it will be a lot smaller.

Lets have a look at another example: $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $\mathcal{E}=\big\{\{1,2\},\{3\}\big\}$. So $\mathcal{E}$ consists of $2$ subsets of $X$. What is $\mathcal{R}$? You can verify yourself that

$$\mathcal{R}=\big\{\emptyset, \{1\},\{2\},\{3\},$$
$$\{1,2\}, \{1,3\},\{2,3\},$$
$$\{1,2,3\}\big\}$$

which is $8$ subsets and $\mathcal{E}\subsetneq\mathcal{R}$.

> The last part is also more misterious to me because from the beginning $\mathcal{R}$ seems smaller from $\mathcal{E}$.

It is not smaller, as we've already established. And the last paragraph is a consequence of the fact that $\mathcal{R}(\mathcal{E})$ is the intersection of all rings containing $\mathcal{E}$, in particular $\mathcal{R}$.